# Copy files from host to server, but only those that already exist in the destination directory

Tags: scp, file-transfer, file-server

Is there a way to transfer files using scp but not all of them, only the subset which already exists in the destination folder?

p.s. all the files have the same extrension (*.JPG), if that matters

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) can do this, with the `--existing`/`--ignore-non-existing` option. From the manual:

> ```
> --existing, --ignore-non-existing
> ```
>
> This tells rsync to skip creating files (including directories) that do not exist yet on the destination.
>
> This option is a transfer rule, not an exclude, so it doesn't affect the data that goes into the file-lists, and thus it doesn't affect deletions. It just limits the files that the receiver requests to be transferred.

Comment: --ignore-non-existing seems to be wrong